# Extending Exception partial class

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, blackboard

I'm using a sample SOAP code generated by wsdl.exe. The object `lastError` is declared like this:

`private Exception lastError;`

**Visual Studio is giving error on build on this line**

`String msg = lastError.Message;`

saying

`'Exception' does not contain a definition for 'Message' and no extension method 'Message' accepting a first argument of type 'Exception' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` :

The `Exception` class generated by wsdl.exe looks like this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(NestedException))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(PersistenceException))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(BbSecurityException))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://gradebook.ws.blackboard")]
public partial class Exception {

    private object exception1Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Exception", IsNullable=true)]
    public object Exception1 {
        get {
            return this.exception1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.exception1Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? The `Exception` class (no relation to `System.Exception` by the way) does not have a property for `Message`...

Comment: I understand Exception class being generated by wsdl does not have a Message property. But I thought it had some relation to System.Exception class so it was inheriting that property?

Comment: No, as you can see from the definition, there is no inheritance to `System.Exception`. Unless you see it explicitly extend the class it won't, it doesn't extend it just because its `partial` with the same name.

Comment: " it doesn't extend it just because its partial" that answers my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`partial` classes don't automatically extend any built-in or non-partial classes by virtue of a shared name. If you want the above `Exception` class to extend `System.Exception`, then the easiest way to do that is to add another partial class and extend it explicitly:

(In some other file)

```
public partial class Exception : System.Exception
{

}
```

You should be aware of issues having a class named `Exception` though. Technically you shouldn't really catch the generic `Exception`, but if you had something like this in your namespace, you may not be catching the exception you think you are:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        DoSomethingThatExcepts();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //You are actually catching the defined Exception, not System.Exception
    }
}
```

So anywhere you use `System.Exception` you may have to fully qualify the name.

Comment: Will use `System.Exception` to be sure. Can't get rid of the custom Exception class generated by wsdl